# The opposite of interference pattern of conventional double slit experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interference

Given an interference pattern which is the exact opposite of the interference pattern of the double split experiment (points where delta r = nλ (n=0,1,2,...)are totally dark and points where delta r = l/2 λ (l=1,3,5, ...) are brightest, with r being the path difference). How do the 2 waves look like and how can they be produced?

Comment: Hint: how can there be destructive interference if the path lengths are equal?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to put a half-wave retarder plate in front if one slit.  That will move the interference fringes by 1/2 space